# UICollectionView custom layout with two cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've been reading online tutorials on `UICollectionView` with different layouts. Also looked at a lot of SO Questions on the subject. But it seems what I am looking might be something more simple but I am stuck on how to go forward.

**The Goal**

I have a `UIViewController` that is embedded in a `UINavigation` controller. I am displaying data in a UITableView which includes:1 UIImageView and three UILabels in each cell. The data is fetched from a server and all works nicely.

I then wanted to have a UIButton that, when tapped, would kick off a cool animation that shows the cells transition into a nice grid view.

It suddenly dawned on me that I needed to use a `UICollectionView` to change between these two cells and ditch the UITableView completely. Tapping the button again, would switch back to the last state (Grid or `UITableView` style)

The grid cell needs to loose one label - but keep the image.

**The problem**

I have spent the last two days reading up on `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I think I could use a Apple's pre-made `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` and just tweak it a little.

I don't know if I need two custom cells or one cell that changes shape between the two views and how the animations must work.

I'm not looking for the exact code to do this - I just need to know which direction I need to go in and if I need to use two custom cells - and how do I change between the two with animation  and not reloading all the data again.

Appreciate any input.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution that was acceptable to my need. If anyone ever has similar needs - this is how you use two different custom `UICollectionViewCell`'s and how to change between the two different cells / layouts.

- First thing is create the customCells in IB - creating the `xib`
  files.
- Then set the up as you need

Since my requirement needed the standard flow layout provided by the class `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` - I just needed to create two custom layouts and tweak them to my needs.

- Create two (or more if needed) classes that subclass `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`

In the implementation - setup the layout as needed. Since I am subclassing the pre-made UICollectionViewFlowLayOut and all I need to do is tweak it - the implementation is pretty simple.

So - for the table view layout I did this:

```
tableViewFlowLayOut.m

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){

        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(320, 80);
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.1f;
    }

    return self;
}
```

This sets each cells width and height to the values I needed. `self.minimumLineSpacing` sets the spacing between the cells. (Spacing between the cell above / below )

Then for the grid layout:

```
gridFlowLayOut.m

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self){

        self.itemSize = CGSizeMake(159, 200);
        self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.1f;
        self.minimumLineSpacing = 0.1f;
    }
    return self; 
}
```

Same as before - however, this time I needed spacing between my cells right edge -

```
self.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.1f'
```

takes care of that.

Right - now to put it all together - in the viewController that has the `UICollectionView`

```
viewController.m

// Import the new layouts needed. 

#import "GridFlowLayOut.h"
#import "TableViewFlowLayOut.m"

//Create the properties 

@property (strong, nonatomic) TableViewFlowLayOut *tableViewLayout;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GridFlowLayOut *grideLayout;

-(void)viewDidLow
{
//Register the two custom collection view cells you created earlier. Make sure you set the correct reuse identifier here. 

[self.tradeFeedCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"TableViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"TableItemCell"];
    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GridViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"GridItemCell"];

}

-(void)viewWillAppear
{
//Create the layout objects

         self.grideLayout = [[GridFlowLayOut alloc]init];
    self.tableViewLayout = [[TableViewFlowLayOut alloc]init];

//Set the first layout to what it should be 

    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout];

}
```

Right - now to change between the layouts with some animation. This is actually very easy to do and only needs a few lines of code -

I called this code in a button method in `viewController.m`

```
-(void)changeViewLayoutButtonPressed
{
//BOOl value to switch between layouts 

    self.changeLayout = !self.changeLayout;

    if (self.changeLayout){
    [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.grideLayout animated:YES];

    }

    else {

          [self.tradeFeedCollectionView setCollectionViewLayout:self.tableViewLayout animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And lastly in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   static NSString *tableCellIdentifier = @"TableItemCell";
    static NSString *gridCellIdentifier = @"GridItemCell";

//BOOL used to detect which layout is active
    if (self.gridLayoutActive == NO){

        CustomCollectionCellClass *tableItemCell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:tableCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Setup the cell

    }
        return tableItemCell;
}else
    {

        CustomCollectionCellClass *gridItemCell= [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:gridCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Setup the cell

    }

    return gridItemCell;
    }
        return nil;

}
```

Of course you will need to conform to the other UICollectionView delegates and setup the remaining stuff.

This actually took me a while to figure out. I really hope it helps others out there. 
If anyone wants a demo project - I'll happily create one and upload to GitHub.

For anyone new to UICollectionViews I highly recommend reading Apple's programming guide on the subject - it was this document which lead me to this solution.

Reference: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Which Cell You registered in StoryBoard?
Can You Share Your Project File

Comment: I don't register any cells in the storyboard. I use xib files and thus, register them via code (As shown in the answer)

Comment: Can You share your project file?
I am getting error saying you should registyer cell nib

Comment: Yes you should register the cell as I do above. I cannot share the project file as it contains sensitive data. Post a question with your code and I will try help you with it.

Comment: You created CustomCell ?
Which names CustomCollectionCellClass.Right?
And Two subclasses of CollectionviewCell names TableView and gridview.Am i going right?

Comment: No, I create one subclass of UICollectionViewCell (CustomCollectionCellClass) and use it to load two different nib files via their respective identifiers. grid/table - however I create two instances of CustomCollectionCellClass and switch between them when the layout changes

Comment: So, You are reloading view on layoutChange?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94192/discussion-between-saheb-singh-and-tander).

Comment: Thanks for your sharing about this. After reviewing the doc link, I think the UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout is the prefer one for this.